# Is there a way to list the files inside a macOS brew package?

Tags: macos, shell, homebrew

Is there a way to list the files inside a **brew** package (already installed) in macOS?

Some equivalent to this command in Ubuntu:

```
$ dpkg -L nginx
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/nginx
/usr/share/doc/nginx/copyright
/usr/share/doc/nginx/changelog.Debian.gz
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`brew list -v $FORMULA` would list all the installed files.

For example:

```
$ brew ls -v bee
find /usr/local/Cellar/bee/1.80_1 -not -type d -print
/usr/local/Cellar/bee/1.80_1/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
/usr/local/Cellar/bee/1.80_1/bin/bee
/usr/local/Cellar/bee/1.80_1/.brew/bee.rb
/usr/local/Cellar/bee/1.80_1/libexec/bin/bee
/usr/local/Cellar/bee/1.80_1/libexec/bin/bee.properties
/usr/local/Cellar/bee/1.80_1/libexec/lib/groovy-cli-commons-2.5.10.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/bee/1.80_1/libexec/lib/bee-1.80.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/bee/1.80_1/libexec/lib/groovy-sql-2.5.10.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/bee/1.80_1/libexec/lib/groovy-2.5.10.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/bee/1.80_1/libexec/lib/commons-cli-1.4.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/bee/1.80_1/libexec/lib/jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.9.13.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/bee/1.80_1/libexec/lib/jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.13.jar
```

See [the man page](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#commands); `ls` is just a shorthand for `list`.